# What is Hiro'omi reading at the beginning of episode 6 of Kyoukai no Kanata?

Tags: beyond-the-boundary

Around the 03:00-mark of episode 6 of Kyoukai no Kanata, Hiro'omi is shown reading a book:

[image: Hiro'omi reading a book]

What book is this?

Answer (score 3):

A brief search into some of the text displayed in the screenshot reveals that this page contains part of the text of "**Eiketsu no Asa**" (永訣の朝; roughly "The Morning of a Final Farewell"; [text](http://ww8.tiki.ne.jp/~takam/bungaku/eiketu.htm); [a reading](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkjJm_w_WpM)), a poem by [Kenji MIYAZAWA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenji_Miyazawa)<sup>1</sup>. "Eiketsu no Asa" is part of his first published collection, *Haru to Shura* (春と修羅; *Spring and Asura*).

In what may prove to be a bit of foreshadowing, "Eiketsu no Asa" was written on the occasion of the untimely death of Kenji's younger sister, Toshi.

---

<sup>1</sup> Miyazawa may be better-known to Western audiences for his novel [*Night on the Galactic Railroad*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_on_the_Galactic_Railroad), which was made into [an anime film](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1441/Night_on_the_Galactic_Railroad) back in 1985.